# jQuery .click() not working on iOS Safari even after trying some of the known fixes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I have been having a little bit of trouble trying to figure this out. I can not get a JQuery .click() event to work on iOS Safari, even after trying some of the known workarounds for this issue.

My code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="mobile-nav-menu">
       <a href="#" onclick="void(0)">
          <img id="hamburger-menu-icon" src="assets/dot-menu.svg">
       </a>
</div>
```

**JS (variable declarations omitted to spare length):**

```
     window.onload = () => {
       hamburgerMenuIcon.click(toggleMobileNavDropdown);
     }

     const toggleMobileNavDropdown = () => {

        if(mobileNavDropdown.height() == 0) {

            mobileNavDropdown.css({
                height: '180px',
                width: '200px'
            })
            mobileNavContents.delay(800).fadeIn(900);

        } else if(mobileNavDropdown.height() == 180) {

            mobileNavContents.fadeOut(400);

            setTimeout(() =>  {
                mobileNavDropdown.css({
                height: '0px',
                width: '0px'
            })
            }, 400)
        }
    }
```

This works absolutely without issue in any browser, both mobile or desktop, other than Safari iOS. I have spent some time on Google and came across a few known work arounds. Here is what I have tried so far without success:

- I have tried applying `cursor: pointer;` to the link. From what I can gather, without this Safari iOS does not register the element as being clickable.
- Since adding the cursor CSS property did not work, I tried to add `onclick="void(0)"` to the HTML as seen in the HTML snippet above. This is another suggestion I came across on Stack, and I am assuming it somehow allows Safari iOS to register the element as being clickable.
- On my third attempt, I tried changing the click event to vanilla JS like so and adding `touchstart and tap`:

  ```
  hamburgerMenuIcon.on("click touchstart tap", toggleMobileNavDropdown);
  ```

So far, nothing gives. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this, firstly this part to stop the events happening multiple time due to bubbling from what I do next:

```
function eventHandler(event, selector) {
    event.stopPropagation(); // Stop event bubbling.
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behaviour
    if (event.type === 'touchend' || event.type === 'touchcancel')
      selector.off('click'); // If event type was touch turn off clicks to prevent phantom clicks.
  }
```

Then for the actual element interactions (you don't need the debounce part necessarily, but I find it helpful, if you like I will link you that plugin, is very light weight and helpful):

```
$(".selection-button").on('click touchend touchcancel', $.debounce(
  100,
  function(e) {

    //whatever you want to do

  }));
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will give that a go! And yes, please link me that, I'd like to take a look.

Comment: Here you go: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/, hope I was able to help, I use that code and it works on every browser as far as I have seen.